# how can I insert data with thread in jdbc?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to insert data with using JDBC.
I write this code :

//I want to start threads here

```
      while(stmt_ver.next()){ 
        stmt_ver.setString(i, "test"+... ); 
        stmt_ver.executeBatch();
        connection_ver.commit(); 
}
```

//I want to finish threads here

How can I do this with thread?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Looks like a littlebit of nonsense to me - no offense. But I bet this code does not what you want.

Comment: I want to insert data in JDBC. But I want to do it with threads not a single thread

Comment: Does it **work** with the single thread? I bet it does not.

Comment: yep it works without thread structure

Comment: this is not whole code, I want to make insert with thread how can I do that?

Comment: Create one and start it, put your code in the `run()` method. ... what part of using a Thread is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Updated answer with code

Threaded class

```
public class MyThreadedClass extends Thread{

     //Do what I need here on a thread
     public void run(){
         //Do what I need here
     }
}
```

Main

```
//Main class
public static class MyProgramMain{

//Program main
public static void main(String[] args) {


                //Send 10 threads
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

                  //Init class (threaded)
                   MyThreadedClass threadedClass = new MyThreadedClass();

                   //Execute code in the class run() method
                   threadedClass.start();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.Think this: for int i ...100 but I want to create 10 thread.so how can ı do that

Comment: Since the class IS a thread, anytime you are instantiating the class and calling the .start() method you are creating a new thread. Beyond that its up to you to do that 10 times (maybe in a for loop, etc...)

Comment: I cant do it. Please give me some example.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
@Override public void run(){
//enter code here
   }
}).start();
```

**EDIT** You want to insert with many threads in parallel ...

There are many different possibilities.

You should read about: Concurrency (concurrent collections) and Executors.

**EDIT 2** I agree with Thomas Uhrig , that introducing Threads could be more a harm than a blessing here.
Why do *you* think it would be helpful?

Comment: One. Oh, I see. You want to do the inserts with many threads in parallel?

Comment: thanks for answering.For example I want to make 10 threads. How can I do that like your code? –

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to answer. You are asking very vague. Try to be clear. Post all necessary code. Try to explain what you did and what you would like to do.

Here is some hint for you. It will not run if you copy and past it, but I think it should make clear what you can try:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < columnCount ){

    // make a new statement
    Statement stmt_ver = new Statement();

    // set your data and make the statement ready
    stmt_ver.set...

    // make a new thread that executes your data
    // and let it run
    new Thread(){ 

        public void run(){

            stmt_ver.addBatch();  
            stmt_ver.executeBatch();
            connection_ver.commit(); 
        }
    }.start();

    i++; 
}
```

This is a very simple solution. It will start a thread it each iteration. Since I/O typically is taking some time, this could improve the execution time of your code. But be aware - threading is not easy. This is a very simple, naive solution. **It could cause more problems than it solves.** If you are not familiar with threads (and it seems like you are not) don't do it!

Comment: And I'm still sure, the iteration will not do what the OP wants. When increasing i by 1, it will set the String to the value the Date had in the last iteration. Plus the indices in the statement will be increased??? If this is working when he executes it, then the actual code must look very different ...

Comment: yes, I agree. All the stmt_ver.set... look very strange. But since he doesn't post more code and since he says that it is working in a single thread, I can't do any more than just re-post his own code.

Comment: thanks for answering.For example I want to make 10 threads. How can I do that like your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MockCommonDao  {

     ArrayList<ArrayList> listOlists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

     public List CommonInsert(List<Object> example)
        {
         List<Future<Object>> listOlists = null;
         ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(example.size());
         List<TransactionImpl> callingList = new ArrayList<MockCommonDao.TransactionImpl>();
         for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) {
             TransactionImpl localImpl = new TransactionImpl(example.get(i));
             callingList.add(localImpl);
         }
         try {

             listOlists = executor.invokeAll(callingList);

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {

         }
         return listOlists;





        }
private class TransactionImpl implements Callable<Object>{
          private Object example;


          TransactionImpl(Object Criteria) {
                this.example = Criteria;

            }


            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

            private class TransactionImpl implements Callable<Object>{
          private Object example;


          TransactionImpl(Object Criteria) {
                this.example = Criteria;

            }


            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

            while(stmt_ver.next()){ 
        stmt_ver.setString(i, "test"+... ); 
        stmt_ver.executeBatch();
        connection_ver.commit(); 
}
      }
      }}
      }
```

This code will make simualtaneous insert depending on value of your threads you want to create for insert.example.size() determines number of insert operations you want to perform.Hope you mean this.